# extracting service principal from AD to keytab

Tags: active-directory, samba, kerberos

Working with Samba 4 as a Windows “domain member”, I’d like to
automate deployment of keytabs. Specifically, I’d like the
equivalent of adding service principals to the appropriate
tables. E. g.

```
# kadmin -k /etc/squid/proxy.keytab -w secret -p kadmin/admin -q "ktadd HTTP/proxy.my.domain"
```

Sadly, MS doesn’t appear to offer `kadmin` interoperability.
Samba has commands like

```
# net rpc vampire keytab all.keytab -U Administrator%secret
# net ads keytab create -U Administrator%secret
```

neither of which however appears to be capable of selectively
extracting service principals. Also, for a non-trivial site
installation I imagine the “vampire” method to require too many
system resources, not to mention the necessary postprocessing
with *ktutil*.

In my test setup, the DC is a Windows2008 server, the client is
running a 3.14-ish Linux, MIT KRB5 1.15.x, and Samba 4.x. The
kerberized service in question is a Squid v3.5.x. Kerberos
integration itself works well when creating keytabs on the DC
(*ktpass*) and then copying them over to each machine manually.
But I’d rather avoid this kind of pedestrian approach.

It doesn’t necessarily have to be a Samba based solution.
That’s just the path I’m investigating ATM.

Answer (score 2):

The only hard part about what you're currently trying to do is extracting the existing password from the account/principal you're creating the keytab for. The rest of the info is readily available via LDAP queries against the DC via the `msDS-KeyVersionNumber` and `servicePrincipalName` attributes.

Assuming the current password on the account isn't set in stone, you could instead just reset/randomize it to something generated by the automation process. Then, you just use ktutil to create the keytab with the now known password and the queried KVNO and SPN(s).

Comment: “extracting the existing password from the account/principal you're creating the keytab for” – I don’t follow. Those are service principals; they don’t have a password. I’m looking for the remote equivalent of ``ktpass princ SRV/srv.foo.bar@EXAMPLE.COM mapuser srv -pass admin-pw out srv.foo.bar.keytab`` that given admin credentials can be executed on *srv.foo.bar*.

Comment: All principals have a password. With the ktpass command, you're just never told what it is. The keytab file is effectively just a hash of that password (potentially multiple hashes using the various supported encryption types).

Comment: Bottom line though, you can generate a perfectly valid keytab file if you know the password, KVNO, and the UPN/SPN associated with the account.

Comment: “All principals have a password.”  – If I’m reading it correctly, RFC 4120 permits passwords for user principals only. Also, MIT Kerberos [definitely creates random keys directly](https://github.com/krb5/krb5/blob/master/src/lib/kadm5/srv/svr_principal.c#L1569) without a diversion through the KDF.

Comment: Apologies, I meant all principals in an Active Directory. Service Principals in AD don't exist without an associated User account/principal. "servicePrincipalName" is a multi-valued attribute associated with a user (or computer) account as is "userPrincipalName".

Comment: Got it! With the password of the associated user I was able to derive a functional keytab using ktutil (in case of a Win 2008  server: ``addent -password -p HTTP/proxybox.example.comi2n@EXAMPLE.COM -k 14 -e rc4-hmac``). While this approach still requires knowlege of which kvno the KDC currently uses, I think this answers the question clearly enough.

Comment: And the kvno is queryable from the msDS-KeyVersionNumber attribute.